# MacBook Pro Mid 2012 briefly displays static after waking from sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, graphics

On my MacBook, whenever I wake it up from hibernation, it briefly displays static for about 2 seconds before showing the login screen, very like an untuned analog TV.  The problem is purely cosmetic, because after that it functions perfectly.  It doesn't seem to happen if I simply sleep it though.

The machine has gone through two OS upgrades, I believe starting from Mountain Lion, which I don't think had the problem, so it may have started with Mavericks, and continues with Yosemite. I currently have everything updated to the latest version.

It's not really a huge issue, but I'd like to fix it if possible. Any ideas?

Comment: First find the wake reason in console log. Note the time stamp for it. Now find the WindowServer after that time stamp and copy those lines here.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue many times over the years. It's kind of like the video ram gets clogged in a way. I've solved it with a [PRAM reset](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH18761). Restart and before the computer actually starts up hold down Option, Command (⌘), P, and R till you hear the second startup chime. Then release the keys. This should take care of that for a while. If you get it again you can look into a [SMC Reset](http://www.sweetwater.com/sweetcare/articles/mac-pro-reset-system-management-controller-smc/) which is a bit more complicated